# In which directory should a node.js program be installed?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, packaging

I'm contributing to an open source node.js project. The installation script for the project works by cloning the git repo to `/home/ProjectName` as root and running the node.js script from there. There is also two configuration files for the project which are supposed to be placed within the root folder of the project.

What is the correct UNIX way to do this? If we follow the Filesystem hierarchy standard, should it be placed in /opt/ProjectName and have node run it from there?
Should the configuration be placed in `/etc/ProjectName`?

Rather than having a script that downloads and starts the node.js script, should we be looking at packaging the software for each distro?

The project is a [Network Video Recorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_video_recorder) software which also generates and stores video recordings. What's a sane default directory to place those recordings?

Comment: I think there's a difference between "Where do I put the source while I'm developing the app?" vs "Where does the production app get installed?"  The former I'd just put in my home directory (e.g., ~/src/app_name).  If it needed deployment, I'd use a container.

Comment: @AndyDalton this is for packaging the app. The maintainer does not recommend using containers as they say containers cause a lot of problems and instead recommend it installing it on a dedicated OS